# Teeshuh mayoys (900) mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

B"H

What is the significance of the number 900 in the torah?

There's a rumor that every number in existence has some sort of significance, seemingly at least up to the highest number in the hebrew alephBet, 900 (final tzadeek), but possibly more even (for example there are many examples of thousands of things or tens of thousands, but I'm not sure how much the highest specific significant number is)

Note: significance besides for the one mentioned above, if it exists

Blessings and success

Comment: For the strangest of strange reasons, there appears to be someone who decided to possibly consider the thought of intellectually contemplating the theory of hypothetically potentially considering the plan to vote this question on the downward direction,I can't even begin the think of starting to contemplate etc why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for starters, it's not enough chariots to defeat Barak's army:

> 3. And the children of Israel cried out to the Lord; for Jabin had nine hundred chariots of iron, and for twenty years he had harshly oppressed the children of Israel.

([Judges](https://www.bible.com/bible/114/JDG.4.3.NKJV)) - the number is mentioned later again in verse 13:

> 13. So Sisera gathered together all his chariots, nine hundred chariots of iron, and all the people who were with him, from Harosheth Hagoyim to the River Kishon.

> 15. And the Lord routed Sisera and all his chariots and all his army with the edge of the sword before Barak; and Sisera alighted from his chariot and fled away on foot.